# Получить данные из POST запроса в PlayFramework

Tags: java, post, playframework

Отправляю post-запросом файл,

```
<form method="post" action="/insertGPS" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="GpsFile">
<input type="text" name="name">
<p><input type="submit" value="Загрузить"></p>
```

потом обрабатываю запрос так:

```
DynamicForm dynamicForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
```

`String Name = dynamicForm.get("name");`

Текст передается нормально, а вот что с файлом делать - не могу понять. Если пытаться получить с помощью dynamicForm.get, возвращает null. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, `DynamicForm` всегда читает запрос как formUrlEncoded, т.е. игнорирует файл(ы).

Попробуйте способ из [доки](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFileUpload)

т.е. примерно так

```
public Result insertGPS() {
    Http.MultipartFormData<File> body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> gpsFile = body.getFile("GpsFile");
    if (gpsFile != null) {
        String fileName = gpsFile.getFilename();
        String contentType = gpsFile.getContentType();
        File file = gpsFile.getFile();

        DynamicForm dynamicForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
        String name = dynamicForm.get("name");

        // ...

        return ok("File uploaded");
    }

    flash("error", "Missing file");
    return badRequest();        
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и поступила)